# How can I disable keyup loopback in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form like below:

```
<div *ngIf="formLabel" style="padding: 0 16px">
            <md-input [(ngModel)]="label.Name" placeholder="Label name" style="width: 100%">
            </md-input>
        </div>
        <md-list-item *ngFor="let label of labels">
            <h3 md-line>
                <md-icon class="fa fa-tag" fontSet="fa" fontIcon="fa-tag" (click)="openFormLabel(label)"></md-icon>
                <a routerLink="/label/{{label.Id}}">{{label.Name}}</a>
            </h3>
</md-list-item>
```

How can I disable {{labe.Name}} auto bind text when I'm typing in md-ipnut ?

Comment: So, when are you going to update `{{ label.Name }}`? I don't think one way binding is going to solve this.

Comment: @choz see my updates.

Comment: @micronyks Your solution will work alright. But I am just wondering why he would use `label.Name` interpolation if he doesn't intend to update it when the value changes. Ofc, leave aside the fact if he wants to update it once an event occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that, use ***one way*** binding like,

```
[ngModel]="label.Name"
```

**Update** :

If you intended to update **label.Name** value after completion of typing, you can use **blur** event as shown here along with ***one-way*** binding

```
<form #f='ngForm' (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f.form)">

          <input (blur)="changeValue(f.form)"   //<<<===here
                 type="text" #Name="ngModel"      
                 [ngModel]="label.Name" 
                 name="Name" >
</form>


export class AppComponent {

       label={};

        onSubmit(f){
          console.log(f.controls.Name.value)
        }
        changeValue(f){
            this.label.Name=f.controls.Name.value;
        }

}
```

**Demo :  https://plnkr.co/edit/D317OeHapT9m4DxgGvO1?p=preview**

Comment: After work with your demo, I think this is a way to resolve my problem. Thank you so much :)